# Material Not Showing on Objects Using Geometry Nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I have a Blender project consisting of multiple objects using geometry nodes, and I noticed that none of the material appear in either the viewport or the final render.

This is the geometry nodes:
[image]

This is the material in the shading view in both material preview and rendered views (the color in the rendered view is from the lights not the material):
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I needed to upgrade to Blender v3. There is a geometry node in v3 called `Set Material` and that's what you use to set the material of the object.

Comment: Alternatively with V2.93 you can use a Set Attribute and set `material_index` attribute. Make sure the actual objects have materials added to them corresponding to the index (first material starts at index 0)